# jq command returns null output while trying to get value based of a key of a JSON file

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

jq command returns null output while trying to get  value based on a key of a JSON file, Below is my json file:

```
{
 "name":"John", 
  "age":31, 
 "city":"New York"
}
```

bash command I'm using to get the value:

```
cat mytest.json| jq -r '.| keys[]' | while IFS= read  key ;  do        
echo $key;   
value=$(jq  -r '."'$key'"' mytest.json);   
echo $value;
done
```

I'm I missing something here

Comment: There is a missing `done` at the end of the shell script, but besides that, it is showing keys and values correctly. Where do you see the null value?

Comment: @mnikolic $value is showing null

Comment: what version of bash and jq do you have? I've tested with GNU bash, version 5.0.17 and jq 1.6 and it's working just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The initial `.` in the first invocation of jq is unnecessary.
2. This variant should work, though it is definitely not recommended:

```
cat mytest.json| jq -r 'keys[]' | while IFS= read -r key ;  do        
echo $key 
value=$(jq --arg key "$key" -r '.[$key]' mytest.json);   
echo $value
done
```

3. You could obtain the same result with just one invocation of jq without any looping; or if you want to loop in bash, consider

```
while read -r key ; do
   read -r value
   echo "$key"
   echo "$value" 
done < <(jq -r 'keys[] as $k | ($k, .[$k])' mytest.json)
```

4. You might wish to consider using `keys_unsorted` instead of `keys`.
5. The snippets in (3) and especially (2) above are somewhat brittle but can easily be robustified, though the details might depend on your requirements.